# Data not reflected on UI when deleting item from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
// Delete Input Fields:-
const [salesProduct, setSalesProduct] = useState(props.inputValue);

const deleteInput = (id, indexValue) => {
 salesProduct.splice(indexValue, 1); // salesProduct is an array when delete 
 let data = salesProduct;
 // when console the data it is giving write out put but data is not reflecting 
 console.log(data);  
 setSalesProduct(data);
}
```

// Below is My Jsx where i am using deleteInput event To Delete Item can any one please help me what i am doing wrong
    salesProduct.map((value, index) => {

```
return (
<tr key={value.id}>    
<td scope="row">
<input id={value.id} value={value.shippingValue}  onChange={ (e) => handleInputAndDropdown(e, value.id, 'cartValue') } className={value.className} type={value.type} name={value.name} title={value.title} placeholder={value.placeholder} />
</td>    
<td>
 <input id={value.id} value={value.taxValue}  onChange={ (e) => handleInputAndDropdown(e, value.id, 'taxValue')}  className={value.className} type={value.type} name={value.name} title={value.title} placeholder={value.placeholder}/>
</td>    
<td>
{showDeleteBtn && <a href="#" onClick={() => deleteInput(value.id, index)}>Delete</a>}
</td>

</tr>
)
})
```

Comment: Please add definition of function `setSalesProduct(data);`

Comment: Also, add your `JSX` code.

Comment: The issue is likely that `.splice` mutates the array in place, so `setSalesProduct(data);` passes the exact same value (the array object) it currently has, so React thinks nothing has changed. You need to create a new array.

Comment: Could you please formulate a question of some kind and not only paste your code?

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is totally different instead of splice I would go with a filter method

```js
// Delete Input Fields:-
const [salesProduct, setSalesProduct] = useState(props.inputValue);

const deleteInput = (id) => {
  const newSales = salesProduct.filter(sale => sale.id != id); 
  setSalesProduct(newSales);
}
```

It would help you returning a new array, instead of the splice that remove the one you wish and return the value to you

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your full jsx code, but what you are probably doing is mapping each `salesProduct` to some html element. If your code looks something like that

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {salesProduct.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          {item}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

E.g. if in the part of your UI where you display salesProduct(s) **you map each `salesProduct` to some div element and the key of that div is the `index` of the sales product**  then you're doing it wrong because, as stated in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) the key must be completely unique, you can read [here](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) on why it's bad to use the index as key

P.S It is very hard to help when I don't see the code in which all the salesProduct are being rendered, so please provide some more information.